# Как сделать динамические роуты?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, карты

Добрый день пишу приложение на Vue.JS, и столкнулся с проблемой, на определенной страницы есть datePicker, с помощью клика я беру оттуда дату и пересылаю на сервер, затем я получаю ответ в в виде координатов, и мне нужно эти координаты обновлять на карте. Координаты хранятся в state. И мне нужно динамическое обновление.

Карта -- Here.com

Код строительство роутинга

```
const routingParameters = {
        mode: 'fastest;car',
        waypoint0: this.$store.getters.startWaypoint,
        waypoint1: this.$store.getters.endWaypoint,
        representation: 'display',
      };
```

Код распределение точек:

```
placesSearch(platform)
      const onResult = function (result) {
        let route;
        let routeShape;
        let startPoint;
        let endPoint;
        let linestring;
        if (result.response.route) {
          route = result.response.route[0];
          routeShape = route.shape;
          linestring = new H.geo.LineString();
          routeShape.forEach((point) => {
            const parts = point.split(',');
            linestring.pushLatLngAlt(parts[0], parts[1]);
          });
          startPoint = route.waypoint[0].mappedPosition;
          endPoint = route.waypoint[1].mappedPosition;

          const routeLine = new H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
            style: {fillColor: 'white', lineWidth: 7, frequency: 1},
          });

          const startMarker = new H.map.Marker({
            lat: startPoint.latitude,
            lng: startPoint.longitude,
          });

          const endMarker = new H.map.Marker({
            lat: endPoint.latitude,
            lng: endPoint.longitude,
          });

          map.addObjects([routeLine, startMarker, endMarker]);

          map.setViewBounds(routeLine.getBounds());
        }
      };
      const router = platform.getRoutingService();

      router.calculateRoute(routingParameters, onResult,
        (error) => {
          alert(error.message);
        });
      placesSearch(platform);
    }
```

И код отправки на сервер:

```
datePicker({commit}, payload) {
      axios.get(url + payload).then((response) => {
        let datePicker = response.data.results[0]
        console.log(datePicker)
        let endWaypoint = `geo!${datePicker.end_location.latitude},${datePicker.end_location.longitude}`;
        let startWaypoint = `geo!${datePicker.start_location.latitude},${datePicker.start_location.longitude}`;
        commit('startWaypoint', startWaypoint);
        commit('endWaypoint', endWaypoint);
      })
    }
```

Comment: Причем здесь роуты?  Просто прокидывайте в карту `startWaypoint` && `endWaypoint` через `computed` || `watch`

Comment: Не особо понял как это сделать

Comment: значение для ключа  `waypoint1` Вы берете напрямую из `Vuex`.  А я предлагю сделать это через `computed` || `watch` https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed

Comment: Что-то типа?  computed: {
    getStart() {
      return this.$store.getters.startWaypoint;
 },
    getEnd() {
      return this.$store.getters.endWaypoint;
    }

Comment: ну а как мне потом эту функцию запихнуть куда нуцжно?

Comment: `waypoint1: this.getStart`  и все

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но не работает(

Comment: остается `watch`

Comment: К сожалению и с watch не работает